# How to return objects created in a function and ignore the ones with error/NA?

Tags: r, fitdistrplus

**I have edited my question**

## Goal

I want to keep only those objects that were successfully created and ignore those that threw errors.

### Example

Please note that this is just a reproducible example. My original dataset is different.

The following function takes any variable of `mtcars` dataset, fits three theoretical distributions, and then returns the goodness of fit stats:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

fit_distt <- function(var) {
  
v <- mtcars[, var]
  
f1 <- fitdist(data = v, distr = "norm")

f2 <- fitdist(data = v, distr = "nbinom")

f3 <- fitdist(data = v, distr = "gamma")

gofstat(f = list(f1, f2, f3), 
        chisqbreaks = c(0, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 
                        5, 10, 20, 30, 40),
        fitnames = c("normal", "nbinom", "gamma"))

}
```

For instance:

```
> fit_distt("gear")
Goodness-of-fit statistics
                                normal    nbinom     gamma
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic 0.2968616 0.4967268 0.3030232
Cramer-von Mises statistic   0.4944390 1.5117544 0.5153004
Anderson-Darling statistic   3.1060083 7.2858460 3.1742713

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                                 normal   nbinom    gamma
Akaike's Information Criterion 74.33518 109.9331 72.07507
Bayesian Information Criterion 77.26665 112.8646 75.00655
```

## Problem

Some theoretical distributions do not successfully fit on a variable, and `fitdist` throws an error:

```
> fit_distt("mpg")
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
 Error in fitdist(data = v, distr = "nbinom") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

This error occurred with `f2` that tries to fit the `nbinom` on a continuous variable `mpg`. But the `norm` and `gamma` successfully fit.

I want to return the `gofstat` for the successfully fit distributions and ignore the ones that threw error.

### Expected output

Even though `f2` is specified in the function, if it throws an error, I still want the following output:

```
> fit_distt("mpg")
Goodness-of-fit statistics
                                 normal      gamma
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic 0.12485059 0.08841088
Cramer-von Mises statistic   0.08800019 0.03793323
Anderson-Darling statistic   0.58886727 0.28886166

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                                 normal    gamma
Akaike's Information Criterion 208.7555 205.8416
Bayesian Information Criterion 211.6870 208.7731
```

## What I tried

Obviously, I can just remove `f2` from the function. But that means repeating all the code for each variable. That's a lot of code! So, I still want to use the function.

And I want to be able to use the function for any variable. With `mtcars$mpg`, the function fails for `nbinom`, but with `mtcars$vs`, the function fails for `gamma`. For any case,I want to skip the fits that threw error and report `gofstat` for fits that worked.

I can use `purrr::possibly` to quietly return a fit result or throw the error without stopping at the error. But I don't know how to return the successfully fit values only in the `gofstat`.

Comment: You could return `my_vector[!is.na(my_vector)]` in the function, or wrap your current function in `na.omit`

Comment: Yes, but that's not my question. I want to return only those mean values that were calculated. When a mean is not calculated, I want to exclude it. `NA` is one possibility, but what if `f11` is not even created?

Comment: You should provide an example of what you mean by that and clarify your post. Your big section "Question" and your example code only mention `NA` values. Also, I'd strongly recommend looking into the `apply` or `map` family of functions, something like: `lapply(my_list_1, mean)`

Comment: @astrofunkswag, clarified and added the appropriate example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with `try`. Try to fit the distribution and only add it to the list you pass to `gofstat` if it works:

```r
library(fitdistrplus)
#> Loading required package: MASS
#> Loading required package: survival


fit_distt <- function(var) {
  
  v <- mtcars[, var]
  
  distributions <- c("norm", "nbinom", "gamma")
  
  fs <- list()
  fitted_distributions <- vector(mode = "character")
  for (i in seq_along(distributions)) {
    # try to fit the model
    fit <- try(fitdist(data = v, distr = distributions[i]), silent = TRUE)    
    
    # if it works, add it to fs. If not, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    if (!inherits(fit, "try-error")) {
      fs[[length(fs)+1]] <- fit
      fitted_distributions[length(fitted_distributions)+1] <-  distributions[i]
    }
  }
  
  gofstat(f = fs,
          chisqbreaks = c(0, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 
                          5, 10, 20, 30, 40),
          fitnames = fitted_distributions)
  
}

fit_distt("mpg")
#> <simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
#> Goodness-of-fit statistics
#>                                    norm      gamma
#> Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic 0.12485059 0.08841088
#> Cramer-von Mises statistic   0.08800019 0.03793323
#> Anderson-Darling statistic   0.58886727 0.28886166
#> 
#> Goodness-of-fit criteria
#>                                    norm    gamma
#> Akaike's Information Criterion 208.7555 205.8416
#> Bayesian Information Criterion 211.6870 208.7731
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your individual list subsets with a single `lapply`. If you get this to return a `NULL` rather than an `NA`, the entry will disappear after being unlisted. The following function will therefore do what you want, as shown in this reprex:

```r
find_mean_of_each_vector_in_a_list <- function(my_list) {
 suppressWarnings(
   as.numeric(
     unlist(
       sapply(my_list,  function(x) if(is.na(mean(x))) NULL else mean(x))
       )))
}

my_list_1 <- list(a = 1:3, b = 5:6, c = 7:10)
my_list_2 <- list(a = 1:3, b = c("a", "b"), c = 7:10)

find_mean_of_each_vector_in_a_list(my_list_1)
#> [1] 2.0 5.5 8.5
find_mean_of_each_vector_in_a_list(my_list_2)
#> [1] 2.0 8.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>